# How to generate python dict from list of file paths

Tags: python, boto3

I am using [this SSM](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameters_by_path) method to fetch a bunch of sensitive credentials from my AWS parameter store. The path syntax allows me to pull a bunch of related credentials all at once, which is cool, but as you can see the return format is more of a list of dicts. I have stripped away things so that I can grab all my parameters in a format like this:

```
{
    '/a/b/c/d/e': 'xxxxxxxx', 
    '/a/b/c/d/f': 'xxxxxx', 
    '/a/b/c/g': 'xxxxxx'
}
```

But I am having trouble passing that format, into some sort of (im assuming recursive) function that re-formats that dict with path keys into an actual nested dict like this:

```
{
    'a': {
             'b': {
                      'c': {
                               'd': {
                                        'e': 'xxxxxxx',
                                        'f': 'xxxxxxx'
                                    },
                               'g': 'xxxxxxx'
                           }
                  }
         }
}
```

Anyone done something like this before?

Comment: Count the keys in the dict, iterate over the count and keep nesting the values until the last one, and that is when you assign the value. Sigh*

Comment: What is your input and what do you need as output? The question is not clear.

Comment: The input is the 1st code snippet, and the desired output is the 2nd snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = {
    '/a/b/c/d/e': 'xxxxxxxx', 
    '/a/b/c/d/f': 'xxxxxx', 
    '/a/b/c/g': 'xxxxxx'
}

output = {}

for key, value in d.items():
    directories = key.split('/')[1:]
    helper = output
    for dire in directories[:-1]:
        if dire not in helper:
            helper[dire] = {}
        helper = helper[dire]
    helper[directories[-1]] = value

print(output)
```

The output was:

```
{
 'a': {
       'b': {
             'c': {
                   'd': {
                         'e': 'xxxxxxxx', 
                         'f': 'xxxxxx'
                        }, 
                   'g': 'xxxxxx'
                  }
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: If this works for you I appreciate to mark it as a solution :). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

You may inherit dictionary like follwoing

```
class RecursiveDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self.__setleaf__(key, RecursiveDict())
        return self[key]

    def __setleaf__(self,key,value):
        super(RecursiveDict, self).__setitem__(key,value)

    def __setitem__(self, key,value):
        keys = key.strip('/').split('/')
        tmp = self
        for k in keys[:-1]:
            tmp = tmp[k]
        tmp.__setleaf__(keys[-1],value)
```

You may use it as follows

```
d = RecursiveDict()
d['/a/b/c/d/e'] =  'xxxxxxxx'
d['/a/b/c/d/f'] =  'xxxxxx' 
print(d)
```

Comment: @rosey this must be the pythonic way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

This approach doesn't work perfectly with what you're looking for, but if your separator is a period instead of a forward slash, it will work perfectly.

1. **Install unflatten from Pypi** (https://pypi.org/project/unflatten/)

   ```
   pip install unflatten
   ```
2. **Code:**

   ```
   from unflatten import unflatten 

   t = {
       'a.b.c.d.e': 'xxxxxxxx', 
       'a.b.c.d.f': 'xxxxxx', 
       'a.b.c.g': 'xxxxxx'
   }

   print(unflatten(t))
   ```

**Input:**

```
{
    'a.b.c.d.e': 'xxxxxxxx', 
    'a.b.c.d.f': 'xxxxxx', 
    'a.b.c.g': 'xxxxxx' 
}
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'g': 'xxxxxx', 'd': {'f': 'xxxxxx', 'e': 'xxxxxxxx'}}}}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `print(unflatten(t))` instead?

Comment: @DirtyBit yes, you're right! Excuse my typo, fixed now. I was trying to see if I could pass in a separator of my choosing, but unfortunately, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote library ([ssmenv](https://github.com/whisller/ssmenv)) that I am using for reading values from parameter store:

```
from ssmenv import SSMEnv

params = SSMEnv("/service/my-service", "/resource/mysql")
```

This way you will fetch all keys under "/service/my-service" and "/resource/mysql" namespace as normalised keys e.g. "SERVICE_MY_SERVICE_DEBUG"